# How to use SimpleImageSlider in Reactjs with an array of images from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of images saved in my firebase firestore documents. I want to show all images as a slide show and i found this react package  that  does that, `react-simple-image-slider`.

My images are saved this way in firestore:

[image]

Now I am retrieving them this way in order to add them to the slider:

```
const [imgUrls, setIMGUrls] = useState([]);
  const imageList = []

firebase.firestore().collection("Properties").where("propertyID", "==", propID).get().then((snapshot) => {

  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

    const {
      imageUrls,
      features
    } = doc.data();

    imageList.push({
      imageUrls: imageUrls,
    })

    setIMGUrls(imageList)
  })
})
```

and using the component this way:

```
                     <SimpleImageSlider
                      width={896}
                      height={504}
                      images={imgUrls}
                      showBullets={true}
                      showNavs={true}
                    />
```

but I am getting an error that reads

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')
    at SimpleImageSlider"
```

How can I fix that?

EDIT:

`console.log(JSON.stringify(images))`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images property should be array of objects where each object has a property `url` as mentioned in the [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-image-slider) section. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const [imgUrls, setIMGUrls] = useState([]);


firebase.firestore().collection("Properties").where("propertyID", "==", propID).get().then((snapshot) => {
  // images from all documents in the snapshot 
  let images = []

  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const { imageUrls } = doc.data();
    images = [...images, ...imageUrls.map(url => ({ url }))]
  })

  setIMGUrls(images)
})
```

Comment: Thank you  for the detailed answer, but i am still getting the same error. Why is that?

Comment: @Derek can you try restarting the dev server? If the issue still persists then can you run  `console.log(JSON.stringify(images))` right before `setIMGUrls(images)` and share the output?

Comment: @Derek I had a typo in `map()`. It's supposed to be `.map(url => ({ url  }))` and not `.map(utl => ({ url  }))` Can you try correcting it ?

Comment: i noticed that and fixed it, that wasn't  the  issue,  check my  edited question to see the output of the  console.log

Comment: @Derek yes I missed the spread operator... can you add `...` before `imageUrls.map(..)` ? See updated answer.

Comment: Sadly, it still doesn't work

Comment: @Derek have you tried restarting the dev server? Also can you confirm you have an array of objects as output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(images))` now?

Comment: Yes i do, check my edited  question

Comment: @Derek that seems to be correct. Best to try restarting local server or reinstalling the packge.

Comment: i did restart multiple times, same issue, can u share with my which variable i would put  in the images = {}  in the SimpleImageSlider?

Comment: @Derek can you just copy the output array and hard code it in useState once and try? Like `const [imgUrls, setIMGUrls] = useState(<TheArrayInOutput>);`

Comment: it works now when it is hard coded, why is that??

Comment: imageList is an empty array is that why? like this const imageList = []

Comment: @Derek yes so I doubt empty array. I checked the source code of the library and apparently it needs at least one elem in the array.. (I just saw element at index 0 is not optional but haven't checked if the lib adds it by default or something). You might want to check that with the maintainer once.

Comment: @Derek you don't need any imageList var.. check the code in my answer

Comment: do i need to json.stringify the images or no?

Comment: @Derek no... the stringify was just to view in console... but set imageURLs would be without stringify... You can try `const [imgUrls, setIMGUrls] = useState([{url: ""}]);` so one empty URL by default

Comment: THAT FINALLY  MADE IT WORK! THANK YOU.

Comment: Cool @Derek, for context, this has something to do with [this line](https://github.com/kimcoder/react-simple-image-slider/blob/master/src/ImageSlider.tsx#L62) in the library.. it's expecting an element at index 0 for some reason :/

Comment: It  works now, but when the page is first reloaded it shows a black image and when i scroll it  starts showing the images, i dont understand why.

Comment: That's probably because the default URL is empty in state. Maybe just add URL to a transparent image and reach out to the developer.